# Regular expression that matches unique numbers repeated N times

Tags: r, regex

I'd like to match numbers that are repeated N times but only are unique numbers. I'm interested in a regular expression solution.

```
vec <- c("00", "01", "02", "06", "07", "65", "87", "88", "66", "777", "999999")
grep("^[6-9]{1,}$", vec, value = TRUE)
#> [1] "87"     "88"     "66"     "777"    "999999"
```

So here I'd like to match only `88`, `66`, `777` and `9999`. `87` should not be matched because it contains two different numbers.

Hints?

Comment: what' s with `"00"`?

Comment: How about `00`?

Comment: Sorry, yeah for this purpose it's only`[6-9]` as you can see from the reg expr. But should apply if I set `[0-9]`.

Comment: `idx <- strrep(6:9, rep(1:6, each = 10)); vec[vec %in% idx]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a backreference:

```
grep("^([6-9])\\1{1,}$", vec, value = TRUE)
[1] "88"     "66"     "777"    "999999"
```

If you want to match numbers repeated N times, then the `{1}` should be N-1 because you already have the first match as the capturing group.

Comment: this is the type of solution I was searching for! Upvote.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Perl backreferences](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Backreferences).

```
inx <- grep("^([6-9])\\g1", vec, perl = TRUE)
vec[inx]
#[1] "88"     "66"     "777"    "999999"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, a more complicated solution. But I wanted to try an other approach using the `tidyverse`:

```
library(stringr)
library(tidyverse),

vec %>% 
  str_split("") %>% 
  keep(function(x) length(unique(x)) == 1 & all(x > 5)) %>% 
  map_chr(paste0, collapse = "")
[1] "88"     "66"     "777"    "999999"
```